# how to get the actual docstring of an attribute

Tags: python, spacy

I wanted to find out what `.ent_iob_` was by doing this:

```
doc = nlp('Hello World!')
token = doc[0]
token.ent_iob_?
```

The help returned these:

```
Type:        str
String form: O
Length:      1
Docstring:  
str(object='') -> str
str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str

Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer
that will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler.
Otherwise, returns the result of object.__str__() (if defined)
or repr(object).
encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
errors defaults to 'strict'.
```

Instead of this:

```
"""
IOB code of named entity tag. "B" means the token begins an entity, "I" means it is inside an entity, "O" means it is outside an entity, and "" means no entity tag is set.
"""
```

Could someone please point out what I did wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just accidentally figured this out:

```
spacy.tokens.token.Token.ent_iob_?
```

will return the desired explanation:

```
Type:        getset_descriptor
String form: <attribute 'ent_iob_' of 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' objects>
Docstring:  
IOB code of named entity tag. "B" means the token begins an entity,
"I" means it is inside an entity, "O" means it is outside an entity,
and "" means no entity tag is set.

RETURNS (unicode): IOB code of named entity tag.
```

Comment: Still, this did not explain why we cannot find the correct docstring for a method/attribute for an instance/object of a token with SpaCy. For other packages such as keras, if we did `model = Model(...)` then we could find the correct docstring by doing `model.fit?`. Was it because in this case we actually initalising an instance of `Model`?